# How can I install Maya 2018 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

I'm kind of new to Ubuntu and all this Linux world. I want to install the most recent Maya version (2018). The thing is that I see a lot of scripts for Maya 2017, but I don't know what I should change in them so it works for Maya 2018.
Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome **Erick** to askubuntu! Please add more details and efforts on your installation process! As I know Maya 2018 is not official supported on Ubuntu or Debian based operating systems.

Comment: I've already installed a lot of professional CAD software on ubuntu, which was not official supported. You should look at this 
 link https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-rpm-packages-on-ubuntu/ , or search for topics like the **rpm** package. Normaly the software runs fine, but you have to put a lot of effort to install it right.